# Unity - How to change player spritesheet while runtime?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, sprite, sprite-sheet

I'm currently working on a 2D pixel Jump'n'Run. I want the player to be able to "buy" new skins for the player-character. I have multiple sprite-sheets. They all have the same structure. I'm using sprite animations.

How can I change the sprite-sheet at runtime? I found the following solution, but it's very resource intense: https://youtu.be/HM17mAmLd7k?t=1818

Sincerly,
Julian

Answer (score 2):

The reason it's so resource intensive in the video is because the all the sprites are loaded in each `LateUpdate()`, which is once per frame. The script looks like it's grabbing all the sprites in the sprite-sheet and loading them every frame so that if the `spriteSheetName` ever changes, it will update the renderer on the next frame.

I don't believe that's necessary and in the video he mentions that it's just being used as an example. What I'd do is move it out of the `LateUpdate()` method and into its own method that can be called only whenever the user wants to change the sprite-sheet. So instead of mindlessly loading the sprites from the sprite-sheet each frame, you'll only load them whenever the user selects it.

That should accomplish drastically cutting down the intensity of this script because you're not loading all the sprites in a sprite-sheet and looping through each of their renderers on every single frame.

Comment: Yeah, I tried this as well. But when I'm doing this it's away again in the next frame and the character is looking as he did before.